# Print number of newlines from a file (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

This code gives compile time error, can anyone help please ?

```
const fs = require('fs')

var str_contents  = fs.readFileSync('./README.md', 'utf8');

var numOflines = str_contents.split('/n').length - 1;

console.log(numOflines);
```

Comment: It seems fine to me (no errors). You might want to use "\n" instead of "/n" if you're looking for newlines though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and I didn't get a compile time error. It logged "0" when it should've logged "12" (in my test README.md). Changing "/n" to "\n" fixed this and the following code worked just fine

```
const fs = require('fs')
var str_contents  = fs.readFileSync('./README.md', 'utf8');
var numOflines = str_contents.split('\n').length - 1;
console.log(numOflines);
```

"\n" is the proper escape sequence for a newline.

Comment: this is what is gives me when I run the code on my mac